# How can I get a data attribute from an array into an h3 on the DOM using js / jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a var that has some data attributes in it.

```
var test = {
  "game": [
    {
      "Title": "blah",
      "Type": "Sports"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to populate the Title in a h3 on the DOM.  This is what I am currently trying to use:

```
$(function(){
  $('#currentGame').val(test.game[0].Title);
});
```

When I do this I don't get an error but nothing shows up on the page.  The #currentGame is the id of the h3.

Comment: What does the HTML for the H3 look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your page contains an H3#currentGame and you want to set its 'title' attribute, you can

```
$(function(){
  $('#currentGame').attr('title',test.game[0].Title);
});
```

On the other hand, if you only wish to set the HTML content of the H3, the text between the <H3> and </H3>, you'd use: `$('#currentGame').html(test.game[0].Title);`

Or `$('#currentGame').text(test.game[0].Title);` if the value of your title is never expected to contain any HTML.

Answer (score 4):

[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is usually used for form elements like input. You will want to use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for escaped text or [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) for html

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was something small.  I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me.